# How to create multiple consumers in Kafka to read same messages from a producer and do different tasks at each consumer after receiving those

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have an use case where in I need to create 3 consumers which can read all the message from a single or more partitions sent by producer. I need my 3 consumers to do 3 different tasks after receiving the same message.

One nice way of doing it is create a consumer group with diffrent group.id by using

> props.put("group.id", UUID.randomUUID().toString())

I have refered following link for this idea.

[Kafka multiple consumers for a partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647544/kafka-multiple-consumers-for-a-partition)

I am stuck up in knowing how I twick ConsumerGroupExample code to achieve this? How do I create multiple consumers? and How do I manage them seperately after receiving the message? Do I need to create multiple objects of ConsumerGroupExample ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create 3 objects with different group.id.

Just one note: use static names for each group (instead of random) to support failover and paralleling the same task on multiple instances.

Comment: And further, based on the groupid I can write 3 diffrent logics for received message right?

Comment: right, each consumer(based on group.id) will get the same messages and you can write different logic for them

Comment: Thanks a lot Anatoly.